# A pattern for returning an object created by multiple repositories

Tags: c#

As ever I'm always looking for patterns to write better programmes. Recently I've spent some time with custom `Repositories` and `DTO`'s. All is well and good but I have a scenario where as I have three `DTO's`:

1. Token
2. User
3. Bio

And three repositories (mapped to DTO's)

1. TokenRepository
2. UserRepository
3. BioRepository

Now if user "A" makes a request, which then calls `GetUserByCredentials(User user);`

I want to craft an object - maybe `UserFacade`? Which has properties of all three tables/Obj's.

So basically what is the best approach or pattern I should consider?

It's worth noting that there are no relationships between the `DTO`'s.

I feel in the long run this will keep all my Repositories /  `DTO's` clean.

**//EDIT**

Just to clarify the database contains relationships. I do not return tbl_User as an object constructed by EF - I map this to a DTO without the use of Code First / Auto Mapper etc.

For Example (Old Method):

```
public User GetUser(string email, string password)
{
    var user = context.tbl_User
        .Where(u => u.Email == email && u.Password == password)
        .Select(y => new User
          {
              UserID = y.UserID,
              Email = y.Email,
              Password = y.Password,
              Token = y.tbl_Token
                      .Where(x => x.UserID == y.UserID)
                      .Select(z => z.TokenName).FirstOrDefault(),
              ProfilePic = y.tbl_Bio.Where(t => t.UserID == y.UserID).Select(p => p.Avatar).FirstOrDefault(),
              RoleID = y.RoleID

          }).FirstOrDefault();

    return user;
}
```

Ideally I'd Like to strip out Token and ProfilePic as these properties would already exist in there own classes (DTO's)

I hope I'm not thinking about patterns too much haha

Thanks for your time!

Regards,

Comment: If there is no relationship between them, how would you know what to query og the other repositories when making the call  `GetUserByCredentials(User user);`

Comment: Apologies, relationship in terms of DTO's. I'll add a snippet of code. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking.  Are you just asking whether you should / how you should create a class that will basically retrieve the user, then retrieve the user's bio, then retrieve the user's token, and create a new composite class?  i.e. your business layer thinks a user has a bio and a token, but your data layer treats them separately?

Comment: @stephen.vakil sorry for the poor explanation - tough to get it across. So a composite class seems more to what I'm after. My data layer has the relationship and my business layer does not - I manually duplicate properties when I need them.

Comment: Have a look at aggregate roots, what I do is that my repositories work on the aggregate roots.  If we take user as aggregate root, then it would have properties for bio and token, and the user repo would be responsible for managing these

Comment: @3dd fantastic! If you could post that as an answer with a short snippet of code and explanation I can mark it as answered - on the assumption no one else posts an answer. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @TezWingfield added my answer, no real code examples needed, I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually make use of repositories to run on my `Aggregate Roots`.

Martin Fowler defined aggregate root as

> a cluster of domain objects that can be treated as a single unit

In this instance `User` will be your aggregate root and `Token` and `Bio` would be properties of `User`.

This way when you need to make changes to either `Bio` or `Token` you will do it through the `UserRepository`

Comment: So just to clarify there is no other abstraction on top of the UserRepository? You use the Repo as the Aggregate root?

Comment: My service layer makes use of the repositories and does the choreographing between the repositories.  The aggregate root is the `User` object, the repository does the data access work for the aggregate root

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for the clear, concise answer/comments!